# DOB IC not working

Tags: buck, direct

i am designing DOB LED light using IC CYT1000AEG.
it is simple circuit only current sense resistor and one capacitor for buffer effect.

my rsense value is 28ohm for 20mA current and LED is 3 nos in series 9V.
when i turn on input supply 230V AC my LED suddenly get damage.

what will be issue..?

attached schematic and IC datasheet for details.
[enter image description here](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1142937/CYT/CYT1000AEG.html)

Comment: It would help if you included your schematic and a BOM. Your statement is you are using a DOB led only gave me 8889 products found for dob led, which one is it. An english version of the data or a translated version would help.

Comment: Hmm that datasheet is in Chinese.  Might be a problem if you can't translate it.  You haven't described your voltage converter.  You should add a schematic and board layout as well if you have one.